# Application Shortcuts and Icons Have Stopped Working

Tags: icons, start-menu

Numerous icons on both my desktop and on my start menu look like this:

[image]

They do not open the application when double-clicked. If I go into the folder where the application is installed, the executable file has its icon, but the app in the start menu list does not. I have tried deleting `iconcache.db`, as well as restarting Explorer, and neither solution works.

In trying to repair Windows 10 using the repair options, Windows is saying I am unable to keep any files, apps, or settings because my current version of Windows might be installed in an unsupported directory. I don't know why it thinks that when I installed it, I kept the volume and directory default. I will add a second edit after doing the repair and reinstalling some apps. It is worth noting re-installation has not fixed the problem in the past.

Comment: I started the repair and took a nap, and when I came back all of my everything was uninstalled. Now that I got windows installed again and updated my issue is gone, but I still don't know what caused it so it could come back.

Comment: There are many things that can cause this. A Repair Install fixed things, but we do not always know what specifically went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

(A) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  Run (in order):

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth   Then
SFC /SCANNOW

Restart and check to see if the problem has been resolved.

(B) If not, make a new, test Windows User Account (Settings, System, Accounts). Log into the new Windows user account and see if icons are working.

(C) If the above does not correct the problem, run a Windows 10 Repair Install.  Start with the option to Keep Everything.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: I also think the destination programs can be accidentally removed so the shortcuts are dead.